# Host a near duplicate 'test' version of your web site, without suffering SEO consequences?

Tags: web, seo

I'm having some minor issues with a web site I'm working on, and I'd like to put up a test version where I make some tweaks to see how things look (I'd like to test on mobile devices as well, so having a live version will certainly be the easiest way to test on multiple devices).

Ideally I'd like to have something like mysite.com/test/ which will start off with an exact copy of the main site. However, I don't want to incur any problems with google etc due to 'duplicate content'.

What would be the best way to avoid such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you'll want a robots.txt file in the root of your domain to instruct the crawler as to which pages it can scan.

http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that I'd manually have to specify each page which would be a pain, but duh, yeah obviously I can specify the full directory. Oddly Google suggest here http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359 not to do this "Google does not recommend blocking crawler access to duplicate content on your website, whether with a robots.txt file or other methods." Seems fine to me though.

Comment: @QuakerOat: Note that Google might still index your blocked URLs (but not the content) if it finds links anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

put 
`<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">`